# Can I put a conditional here in the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to have the initial datepicker to get the date of today of which I can already do, at this point, `selected2Date` still does not exist. Then, I want to check in the value if `selected2` was true and instead of displaying the date of today, it will display the date of `selected2Date`.

```
 const [selected2, setSelected2Date] = useState(new Date());
```

The code if `selected2Date` is still empty.

```
                          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                                  <DatePicker
                                    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                    value={selected2}
                                    onChange={setSelected2Date}
                                    fullWidth
                                  />
                                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

The code if `selected2Date` is not empty. Can I put a conditional here in the `value`?

```
 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                                      <DatePicker
                                        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                        value={user.choices?.selected2}
                                        onChange={setSelected2}
                                        fullWidth
                                      />
                                    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: What is `selected2Date`? What do you mean by "if `selected2` was true"? And where does `user.choices.selected2` come from?

Comment: @rayhatfield sorry, I've edited it already. In the first code, it's a form where the user can select the date. Is there some way where I can use that DatePicker to also display the value of the saved data?

Comment: You want when `setSelected2Date` is empty then get the value from `user.choices.selected2`. am i right ?

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya is there like a condition where if `user.choices.selected2` exist, it will display it's value in the same datepicker?

Comment: You mean like `value={user.choices?.selected2 || selected2}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If value exist in `user.choices.selected2` then get from the `user.choices.selected2` otherwise get from the `selected2` !

try below code.

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
  <DatePicker
    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
    value={user.choices.selected2 ? user.choices.selected2 : selected2}
    onChange={setSelected2}
    fullWidth
  />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <DatePicker
   format="MM/dd/yyyy"
   value={user.choices ? user.choices : selected2}
   onChange={setSelected2}
   fullWidth
  />
```

try this
or if you are geting value from user,choices.selected2 then

```
<DatePicker
   format="MM/dd/yyyy"
   value={user.choices ? user.choices.selected2 : selected2}
   onChange={setSelected2}
   fullWidth
  />
```